# All items that each of them match all a collection keywords

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity

I have two Entity Framework entities, many-to-many related:
Person: PersonID
        PersonName
        KewordS (Navigation Property)

Keyword: KeywordID
         KeywordName
         Persons (Navigation Property)

In addition, I have a collection (say, MyFilters) with some KeywordID’s.

I want to get all the persons that each of them match all the KeywordID’s in the MyFilters collection. 
What should be the appropriate LINQ query to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
_context.Persons.Include("Keywords")
    .Where(p => MyFilters.Count() == p.Keywords.Count())//equal amount
    .Where(p => p.Keywords.All(k => MyFilters.Contains(k.KeywordID)));//and all id match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq intersect. If the intersection count matches the MyFilters count, it means that all the MyFilter keywords were found for that Person.

```
List<int> MyFilters = new List<int>() { 1,2 };
var peopleMatchingAllKeywords = people.Where(pers =>
MyFilters.Intersect(pers.KeyWords.Select(y => y.KeywordID)).Count() == MyFilters.Count());
```